# How do I update a line from a text file in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, append, text-files, overwrite

I'm writing a banking system where as the user deposits or withdraws funds, the balances in the text file should be updated accordingly.

```
        void saveFiles(int index) throws IOException{
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = new Date();

        BufferedWriter twriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Transactions.txt", true));  
        BufferedWriter fwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Customers.txt", true));

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(twriter);  

        //update to Customer.txt file
        outputFile.println(people[index].getCustID() + "," +people[index].getTitle() + "," +people[index].getfName() + ","+people[index].getlName()+ ","
        +people[index].getUsername() + "," +people[index].getPassword() + ","+people[index].getSSN() + ","+people[index].getUniqueID() + ","
        +people[index].getSightkey() + ","+ FCA + "," + TSA + "," + people[index].getSoarAcctBal());

        //update Transactions.txt file
        output.write((dateFormat.format(date) + "," +people[index].getCustID() + "," +numbers[index].getCheckingAcctNum() + "," + transferAmount + "," + "Withdraw" + "," + people[index].getSoarAcctBal()));

        outputFile.flush(); 
        outputFile.close();
        output.flush();
        output.close();     
        }
```

Loading the Customer File

```
        //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
        public GEBank() {
            people = new Customer[4];
        }

    //LOAD CUSTOMERS FILE
    void loadCustomers() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ParseException{
        BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customers.txt"));
        //String that holds current file line.
        String custID = "", title = "", fName = "", lName = "", username = "", password = "", SSN = "", uniqueID = "", sightkey = "", 
                checkingAcctBal = "", savingsAcctBal = "", soarAcctBal = "", line = "";

        //Line number of count
        int i = 0;

        //Read the first customer
        line = inputFile.readLine();

        //load the array
        while (line != null)
        {   //Get each item from the line, stopping at the comma separator
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

            //Get each token and store it in the array
            custID = st.nextToken();
            title = st.nextToken();
            fName = st.nextToken();
            lName = st.nextToken();
            username = st.nextToken();
            password = st.nextToken();
            SSN = st.nextToken();
            uniqueID = st.nextToken();
            sightkey = st.nextToken();
            checkingAcctBal = st.nextToken();
            savingsAcctBal = st.nextToken();
            soarAcctBal = st.nextToken();

            //Instantiate each customer
            people[i] = new Customer(Integer.parseInt(custID), title, fName, lName, username, password, 
                    Integer.parseInt(SSN), uniqueID, sightkey, Float.parseFloat(checkingAcctBal), Float.parseFloat(savingsAcctBal), Float.parseFloat(soarAcctBal));

            //Get the next customer
            i++;
            //System.out.println(username);
            //Read the next customer
            line = inputFile.readLine();

        }
            inputFile.close();
            //System.out.println("The Customer Info file is loaded.");
    }
```

This is my transferFunds method. I was thinking I could set the new balance and write that set balance to the file, but it wasn't working I might've been doing it wrong.

```
//TRANSFER FUNDS METHOD
    void transferFunds(int index) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = new Date();

        int transferchoice = -1;

        do{
        System.out.println("\n-- TRANSFER FUNDS MENU --\n");
        //transfer from checking to savings
        System.out.println("1: Checking Account to Savings Account");
        //transfer from savings to checking
        System.out.println("2: Savings Account to Checking Account");

        System.out.println("\nMake a selection from the above menu options: ");
        transferchoice = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        //show account numbers of customer
        System.out.println("\n-- ACCOUNT NUMBERS --\n");
        System.out.println("Checking Account Number: "+numbers[index].getCheckingAcctNum());        
        System.out.println("Savings Account Number: "+numbers[index].getSavingsAcctNum());
        //show account balances of customer
        System.out.println("\n-- CURRENT BALANCE --\n");
        System.out.println("Checking Account Balance: $"+people[index].getCheckingAcctBal()+".");       
        System.out.println("Savings Account Balance: $"+people[index].getSavingsAcctBal()+"."); 

        System.out.println("\nHow much would you like to transfer?");
        transferAmount = Float.parseFloat(input.readLine());

        System.out.println("\nBusiness Date & Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));

        //FROM CHECKING TO SAVINGS ACCOUNT
        FCA = (people[index].getCheckingAcctBal() - transferAmount);
        TSA = (people[index].getSavingsAcctBal() + transferAmount);

        //FROM SAVINGS TO CHECKING ACCOUNT
        FSA = (people[index].getSavingsAcctBal() - transferAmount);
        TCA = (people[index].getCheckingAcctBal() + transferAmount);

        saveFiles(index);

        if(transferchoice == 1){
            System.out.println("\nYou've chosen to transfer $" +transferAmount+ " from your Checking Account to your Savings Account.\n"
                    + "\n-- UPDATED BALANCE --\n"
                    + "\nChecking Account Balance: $"+FCA+//money[index].setCheckingAcctBal(FCA)
                    "\nSavings Account Balance: $"+TSA+""
                    + "\nFunds successfully transferred");  //confirm the transaction

        }else if(transferchoice == 2){  
            System.out.println("\nYou've chosen to transfer $" +transferAmount+ " from your Savings Account to your Checking Account.\n"
                    + "\n-- UPDATED BALANCE --\n"
                    + "\nChecking Account Balance: $"+FSA+
                    "\nSavings Account Balance: $"+TCA+""
                    + "\nFunds successfully transferred");  //confirm the transaction

        }
            if(people[index].getCheckingAcctBal() < transferAmount && people[index].getSavingsAcctBal() < transferAmount){
                System.out.println("We're sorry, you do not have sufficient funds to complete this transaction.  Transaction Cancelled.\n\n");
                return;
            }
            //Ask customer if they would like to view another balance
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to make another transfer? [Enter y/n]: ");
            moretransfers = input.readLine().charAt(0);
            }while (moretransfers == 'Y' || moretransfers == 'y');
            //If moretransfers is no, then show displayLoginMenu method
            if (moretransfers == 'N' || moretransfers == 'n')
            { displayLoginMenu(index);}
    }
```

The following is my appended text file after the user transferred $400.00 from one account to another. It's creating the last line. What I want it to do is to find this line "people[index]" and then replace it with the updated output

```
100,Ms,Jane,Doe,10ann,guy,1234,brunch,yellow,20000.00,5000.00,2000.00
101,Mr,John,Smith,1mark,girl,2345,lunch,gray,10000.00,3000.00,6000.00
102,Ms,Jenaya,Joseph,2jjPM,jj2,6789,breakfast,green,40000.00,20000.00,80000.00
103,Mr,Edward,Donkor,05001,1005,5432,dinner,blue,25000.00,7100.00,8000.00

101,Mr,John,Smith,1mark,girl,2345,lunch,gray,9600.0,3400.0,6000.0
```

Can anyone help with this? I've been researching and I see that you can create a temporary file and then overwrite the information into a new file. But I'm still unsure on exactly how to do this. I'm still new at Java, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NEVER MODIFY A FILE INLINE! Write the modified contents to a new file and then rename to the old one. Also, if you are a banker, your clients really won't thank you for using `float`s :p

Comment: Assuming you don't care about the content of the old file, you should simply modify whatever data in your customer array you need updated, and then make a parser that translates the array to comma separated lines of text, and use that to overwrite the old file with your new data

Comment: Also, swap your people array out with an ArrayList. If you add another line to your file, your code breaks

Comment: @Scherling Ok. And this would update the line I want changed and then rewrite the unchanged lines? Then delete the old file and create a new file with the updated data? Do you have an example that you can show me? I've been trying to do it for the last few days but I keep hitting a brick wall.

Comment: @fge Noted. And I thought I was using floats. You do mean for the balances, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean for the balances. `float` severely lacks in precision, you should at least use `double`, or best for monetary amounts, `BigDecimal`.

Comment: You could make your classes serialiazable instead of this file nonsence

Answer (score 2):

> How do I update a line from a text file in JAVA?

You don't.

Not in Java, not in C, not in C#, not in Python, not in Ruby, not in perl, not in Brainfuck. Not in ANY LANGUAGE.

Modifying a text file inline is a surefire guarantee that you can't tell what will be happening, but in (100 - epsilon)% of cases, with epsilon being *very* close to 0, you'll lose *at least* the original contents of the file.

Write the modified contents in a *new file*, and then rename atomically to the old one. As luck has it, java.nio.file has `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` for you.

(you can still mmap() the file though, with `FileChannel.map()`; but this is only generally done on files with *fixed size* records; such is not a text file. Remind that a same character can turn out to be more than one byte depending on the encoding you use.)

Comment: Eh, not really. It works in [pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: @Mr.777 yes, such a language actually exists

Answer (score -1):

Eh you can look at this if it helps. Easy to read.

```
public class ExampleTextEdit {

public static String APPLICATION_LOCATION;
public static File textFile;
public static BufferedReader reader;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    APPLICATION_LOCATION = ExampleTextEdit.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    textFile = new File(APPLICATION_LOCATION + File.separator
            + "mytextfile.txt");
    try {
        if ( !textFile.exists()) {

            textFile.createNewFile();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    textFile));
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                writer.write("this that " + i);
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } else {
            loadText();
            File f = new File(APPLICATION_LOCATION + File.separator + "temp.txt"); 
            f.createNewFile();
            String temp;
            BufferedWriter writeNew = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f)); 
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (temp.contains("" + 14))
                    writeNew.write("lol changed"); 
                else 
                    writeNew.write(temp);
                writeNew.newLine();
            }
            writeNew.flush();
            writeNew.close();
            reader.close();
            textFile.delete();
            f.renameTo(textFile);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void loadText() throws Exception {
    String line;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

}
```

You don't need to be too fancy with stuff until you get more familiar with the libraries stick to what you know.

Comment: Why are you throwing `Exception` instead of specific exceptions?!

Comment: Because I can read the stacktrace anyway. If you read the stacktrace and don't understand which exception it is you have issues...

Comment: That's not a reason to delegate the `throws` declaration to take `Exception`. [Methods written like this are generally unmaintainable](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html) and you'll be causing more trouble, such as `ThreadDeath` being caught incorrectly. Convenience is no substitute for proper code.

Answer (score -1):

I may have figured it out.

```
        void saveFiles(int index) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Customers.txt")));
        String uname = people[index].getUsername();
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) 
        {
            if(line.indexOf(uname)!=-1)
            {
                //do your logic here
                sb.append(people[index].getCustID() + "," +people[index].getTitle() + "," +people[index].getfName() + ","+people[index].getlName()+ ","
                        +people[index].getUsername() + "," +people[index].getPassword() + ","+people[index].getSSN() + ","+people[index].getUniqueID() + ","
                        +people[index].getSightkey() + ","+ FCA + "," + TSA + "," + people[index].getSoarAcctBal() +"\n");
            }else{
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } 
        br.close();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Customers.txt")));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
        out.print(sb.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        }
```

But my output is like this now:

```
100,Ms,Jane,Doe,10ann,guy,1234,brunch,yellow,20000.00,5000.00,2000.00101,Mr,John,Smith,1mark,girl,2345,lunch,gray,9600.0,3400.0,6000.0102,Ms,Jenaya,Joseph,2jjPM,jj2,6789,breakfast,green,40000.00,20000.00,80000.00103,Mr,Edward,Donkor,05001,1005,5432,dinner,blue,25000.00,7100.00,8000.00
```

How do I print each instance to a new line?